# Issue with timezones

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, google-calendar-api

I am trying to schedule the meeting using google calendar API.
But, due to the time zone issue, the meetings are scheduled at different timings in different country's time zones.
`await calendar1.freebusy.query({ resource: { timeMin: meetingStartTime, timeMax: meetingEndTime, timeZone: countryTimeZone, items: [{ id: email }], }, })`
So, How should I handle the different timezones so that the meeting can be scheduled at the same time in different countries.

Comment: can you give an example of the time a meeting is showing for different timezones -when you schedule the meeting, I'd assume the timezone is specified, so, can't see why google calendar would get it wrong

Comment: So, a meeting scheduled at your location for say, 6:00pm comes up as 12:30pm in London, or 1:30pm in Paris ... is that the issue?

Comment: Yes, I want to schedule the meeting at the same time at each and every location in the world.

Comment: Eg. If I provide the time to be 8:00 AM, it will schedule the meeting on different times based on the country in which I am using this function.

Comment: But, I want to schedule the meeting at 8:00 AM only in the calendar for every country.

Comment: so, if you schedule for 8:00am YOUR time where you are, you want the meeting to be 8:00AM GMT in London, and 8:00AM GMT+1 in Paris etc?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. I want to show the event at 8:00 AM in the google calendar.

Comment: well if it's a shared global calendar, then you're out of luck. Perhaps have separate calendars for each location for such things.

Comment: No, It is not a shared global calendar. I just want to insert an event at 08:00 AM in the user's google calendar without taking the time zone into consideration.

Comment: So, How is calendly doing the same?